# Insert file displayed as icon without displaying long file name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a file to Excel, mostly Outlook mail, but I want to limit their size of the icon.

If created from file (Outlook mail), the file is large due to the length of the file name.
[image]

If displayed as icon only it is ok, but when I save the document, the file resumes its original appearance (icon and name).

Satisfactory solutions:

1. importing the file and displaying it as an icon only, but so that it doesn't change after saving;
2. removal of the title - the icon itself would remain;
3. inserting another icon (shape) that would be a link to the inserted file

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OtherFormat As String

    Dim objInserted As Object
    Dim rngSize As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    OtherFormat = "packager.dll"

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Szacowania")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G16:G100")) Is Nothing Then

        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In Target
            With cel
                'kolumna H - Analiza
                If Target.Column = 7 Then
                    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="All Files (*.*),*.*")

                    sh.Range("G" & Target.row).Select
                    If FileToOpen <> False Then
                        activesheet.OLEObjects.Add( _
                        Filename:=FileToOpen, _
                        Link:=False, _
                        IconFileName:=OtherFormat, _
                        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                        IconIndex:=0, _
                        IconLabel:=FileToOpen). _
                        Select

                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel has a coments field which you can reach by VBA as well. I would store the original long file name there and place by a shortened ones.

Comment: will you show how?

Comment: Worksheets(1).Range("E5").Comment.Text = "long file name"

Comment: I really don't know how this is supposed to work with my code. The imported file is not in the cell

Comment: sh.Range("G" & Target.row).comment.text = "long file name" or if you have selected it before, selection.comment.text = "long file name"

Comment: If I get shape selected I get error: Object doesn't support this property or method, If I add sh.Range("G" & Target.row).comment.text = "long file name" after import file (If FileToOpen <> False then) I get compile error: Assignment to constans not permitted.

Comment: The filename go in the cell. Or the info how to get it from a server or whatever. Do you really want to store a file(s) in a sheet ? I just would store the file location. But hey, it is your (self BS created) problem :) Not mine ones

Comment: Yes, I need store files in a sheet - do you have any idea how to do it as I need?